# A simpler alternative to Google Maps control for WPF (not necessarily Google Maps)

Tags: .net, wpf, google-maps

I am looking for a Google maps library/API/.NET function that simply shows the map of a location from given co ordinates and zoom, and display it on canvas, and allow me to take screenshot of it.

I have done some search, and found these:

1. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html
2. http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

But these are too complicated for a simple requirement, I am looking for something simpler that I can set up simply and in a short time. And it should be free.

Comment: Does it have to be Google, or can you use Bing Maps?  Microsoft has just released a beta for a WPF Bing Maps control:  http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/08/23/announcing-the-bing-maps-wpf-control.aspx

Comment: No, it does not have to be google! Any map that allows to zoom at city level, just show roads will do! And thanks for the suggestion! I'll check it! I have changed the title of the question accordingly as well.

Comment: @ssyladin: Now that the question has been modified, I guess your comment should be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a re-post of the question comment:

Does it have to be Google, or can you use Bing Maps? Microsoft has just released a beta for a WPF Bing Maps control: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/08/23/announcing-the-bing-maps-wpf-control.aspx

[Edit: Additional information]

If the current (1/1/2012) "beta" label scares you a bit, you can always host the Bing Maps Silverlight control in your application.  A bit kludgeyier, but it provides a nice, clean CLR interface.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884.aspx.

Comment: Bing Maps are awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can spend money, have a look at [DevExpress for WPF](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/wpf-features.xml). Though I never used this particular control, the controls are easy to use in the beginning, and - with a learning curve - you can achieve complex tasks, too.

Comment: Only free alternatives are required. But thanks, i'll look at it too!

Comment: [DevExpress WPF Map Control - it's FREE to all MSDN Subscribers](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2011/12/02/wpf-map-control-it-39-s-free-to-all-msdn-subscribers.aspx)